# Angular Directive with ngScope using controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a simple directive that is a combo of an editor and selector for objects.

In the trimmed down example a user should be able to edit a `person` within the directive, and ultimately select a person, which is bound to `ng-model` so they have a reference to person they selected.

My issue is I'm not sure the best way to get the `ng-model` passed in bound to the selected person on my controller.

I have created a plunker for this here : http://plnkr.co/edit/usWpu82VXHIE3R2vgHgv?p=preview

Here is what my directive looks like

```
  angular
    .module('pe')
    .directive('personEditor', PersonEditorDirective);

  function PersonEditorDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'personEditor.html',
      controller: PersonEditorCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      }
    };

    PersonEditorCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'dataservice'];
    return directive;

    function PersonEditorCtrl($scope, dataservice) {
      var vm = this;
      $scope.vm = vm;

      vm.people = dataservice.getPeople();
      //set selected to the first
      vm.person = vm.people[0];
    }
  }
```

In my directive controller, `vm.people` is an array of all the people.  `vm.person` is the currently selected person, which i would like to be bound to whatever the consumer passes as `ng-model`.

Using the directive would be something like this

```
 <person-editor ng-model='vm.selectedPerson'></person-editor>

 <span>The currently selected person is {{vm.selectedPerson.name}}</span>
```

Within my controller I know that `$scope.ngModel` is the object that they have passed in, and I can change that or whatever, but what is the best/easiest way to get that bound to my controller's `vm.person`?

The only way i've got this working how I want is to watch for when the select element changes it's selection, and then manual set `$scope.ngModel = vm.person`, which feels like the wrong way to do it.

Can I get some methods for achieving what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular 1.3, you can tell the directive to bind the isolate scope values to the controller instance using `bindToController`. With it, `ngModel` is now attached as the `person` property on the controller instance rather than the $scope...

```
var directive = {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'personEditor.html',
  controller: PersonEditorCtrl,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  scope: {
    person: '=ngModel'
  },
  bindToController: true
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5nMX2d0H57StgkAyD6YX?p=preview)

Comment: amazing, all the reading i've done over past 2 days about directives and missed that...thanks a bunch!

Comment: actually running into strange issues now where this works in plunker, but no on a local server (tried with mongoose and iis express)

Comment: Your local source is running Angular 1.3? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm dumb and downloaded an older plunker, but your comment solved my problem in the real app...wasn't using angular 1.3 :).  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it works now! And I agree that `bindToController` isn't very visible in the documentation (if it's even there at all). I only know about it because I came across a while back and waited for 1.3 to be released to use it. Before that, to get 2-way binding working in that scenario I had to inject $scope and use Object.defineProperty getters/setters.